# How can i be able to toggle "checkbox" for dynamically cloned or generated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, formvalidation.io

[image: I am trying to add dynamic checkboxes but after adding them i am unable to check them on click]

Hi guys, I am adding input fields i.e checkboxes dynamically using formValidation.min.js where i was successful in adding the checkboxes but unfortunately i am unable to check them or toggle checked status on any of the checkboxes that are created dynamically. can anyone help me figure this out please!

Thanks in advance!

Here is a piece of my code

```
<form action="" id="createQuestionForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
                                            <input type="text" name="item[0][objective]" class="form-control">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="item[0][status]">
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButton"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Template -->
                                        <div class="input-group hide" id="bookTemplate" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
                                            <input type="text" name="objective" class="form-control">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <input type="checkbox" value="2" class="form-control checkbox-status" name="status">
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButton"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    bookIndex = 0;

    $('#createQuestionForm')
       // Add button click handler
       .on('click', '.addButton', function() {
            bookIndex++;
            var $template = $('#bookTemplate'),
               $clone    = $template
                                .clone()
                                .removeClass('hide')
                                .removeAttr('id')
                                .attr('data-book-index', bookIndex)
                                .insertBefore($template);

            // Update the name attributes
            $clone
               .find('[name="objective"]').attr('name', 'item[' + bookIndex + '][objective]').end()
               .find('[name="status"]').attr('name', 'item[' + bookIndex + '][status]').end();
       })

       // Remove button click handler
       .on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
            var $row  = $(this).parents('.input-group'),
               index = $row.attr('data-book-index');

            // Remove fields
            $('#bookForm')
               .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="item[' + index + '][objective]"]'))
               .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="item[' + index + '][status]"]'));

            // Remove element containing the fields
            $row.remove();
       });
});
```

Anyone with an idea on how to make the checkboxes that are cloned checkable??

Comment: The code you've shown isn't really enough of a complete example to recreate the problem. However, you should be able to check/uncheck dynamic checkboxes by default. The only way it wouldn't work is if you have some JS interfering with that event, but you've not shown anything which would do that.

Comment: I have actually tried to eliminate most js that i may think is interfering with the checkbox but its only happening on checkbox!